# How do I run a sister script on a raspberry pi pico using code inside the main.py script?

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

So I have a raspberry pi pico, which on boot, runs main.py. I have a sister script on the Pico, and I was wondering if there was a function or way to run one of these sister scripts, by using code in main.py. I would also like it to only run the sister script, and not go back to main.py until the Pico reboots.

Something like this:

If variable1.value == 1:
run sisterScript.py

I have tried putting the entire sister script into a function (imports and all) which I can then import and run from the main.py script. While it does call the sister script, it goes back to the main.py script. I would like it to stay on the sister script, after the main script had the command to switch.

Answer (score 0):

To stay on side-loaded script- make it so it never finishes it's job. One of option- create endless loop

on `sisterScript.py`

```
# do stuff
while(True):
  # do more stuff
  # and do not leave this loop
```

on `main.py`

```
If variable1.value == 1:
  import sisterScript
```